# Is $\{(x,y,z,0)\in\mathbb{R}^4:x^4+y^2+z^2=1\}$ diffeomorphic to $S^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I was working on Problem 5-1 of *Smooth Manifolds* by Professor John Lee, and it lead me to wanting to show that 
$\{(x,y,z,0)\in\mathbb{R}^4:x^4+y^2+z^2=1\}$ is diffeomorphic to $S^2$, and that is supposed to be $x^4$, not $x^2$.

The diffeomorphism I suspect is $(x,y,z,0)\mapsto (\operatorname{sgn}(x)x^2,y,z)$. This is the only way I could think of making the map bijective. But I'm having a hard time telling if the inverse is smooth.

I think the inverse map is $(a,b,c)\mapsto (\sqrt{a},b,c,0)$ if $a\geq 0$, and $(a,b,c)\mapsto (-\sqrt{-a},b,c,0)$ if $a\leq 0$. This both seem smooth away from zero, but I'm not sure about smoothness at the origin.

Comment: Try with partial maps. For the part where $|x|<1$, both your set and $S^2$ are diffeomorphic to a cyclinder via $(x,y,z)\mapsto (\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}},\frac{z}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}$. And for $x>0$ as well as $x<0$ your maps are smooth. Finally, where the maps of this atlas overlap, the transitions are smoot.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this is part of Problem $5$-$1$ of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (second edition). Professor Lee participates on this site and has previously answered questions arising from his book (not generally problem solutions though). If you mention that this problem arises from that book (if it did), he may see it and decide to provide some insight. Of course, he has every right to say nothing.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Ok thanks, I will do that.

Comment: Is the map $x\mapsto\text{sgn}(x)x^2$ smooth? I think it is not twice differentiable. Furthermore, since the first derivative at $0$ vanishes, the inverse is not differentiable.

Comment: This shape is called a [superquadric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superquadrics).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they both are smooth convex sets, the "central projection" maps:
$$\pi:C\to S,\qquad \pi(x,y,z)=\frac{(x,y,z)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}},$$
$$\pi^{-1}:S\to C,\qquad \pi^{-1}(x,y,z)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{(1-x^2)+\sqrt{1-2x^2+5x^4}}}\;(x,y,z)\tag{1}$$
are differentiable as a consequence of the Dini's theorem, since the "scale ratio" function is the inverse of a smooth map. For instance, the second "scale ratio" is found by solving
$$ k^4 x^4 + k^2 (1-x^2) = 1.$$
It is not too difficult to check "by hand", too, that the two maps given in $(1)$ are smooth.

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious, how did you compute $\pi^{-1}$?

Comment: @TiffanyHwang: just explained :D

Comment: Thanks! What is a "scale ratio" function? Is there a source to learn this technique? It seems useful.

Comment: It is just a fancy name I used on the moment to denote functions of the form $(x,y,z)\to \kappa_{x,y,z}(x,y,z)$ where $\kappa$ is a scalar function.

Comment: The only idea here is that when dealing with scalar functions to find an inverse or to prove smoothness is way easier.

Comment: What lead you to set $k^4x^4+k^2(1-x^2)=1$? I solved for $k$ to find $k=\pm\sqrt{\frac{x^2-1\pm\sqrt{1-2x^2+5x^4}}{2x^4}}$? Which kind of looks like what you wrote.

Comment: Oh, you're setting $\pi^{-1}(x,y,z)=(kx,ky,kz)$ and solving for $k$ under the condition that $(kx)^4+(ky)^2+(kz)^2=1$?

Comment: @TiffanyHwang: Exacly. The two sign have to be chosen positive, and if you multiply the argument of the square root by $\frac{(1-x^2)+\sqrt{\ldots}}{(1-x^2)+\sqrt{\ldots}}$ you get my $(1)$.

Comment: @Tiffany: There's a short way to prove that this map $\pi$ is a diffeomorphism. Look at the global rank theorem (Thm. 4.14 in ISM).  And note that to prove $\pi$ has constant rank on $\mathbb S^2$, you only need to prove that it's an immersion or a submersion.

Comment: @JackLee. Can we argue that the regular level set above is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2$  without construct a particular diffeomorphism? (because i don't have enough experience to do that). I think maybe i can use Regular Level Set theorem (Corr 5.14), which imply that the level set is compact and have dim$=2$. But then i don't know how to proceed.

Comment: @Sou: I don't see how you could do it without constructing an explicit diffeomorphism. You're right that Cor. 5.14 implies that the level set is compact and 2-dimensional, but that's a long way from proving it's diffeomorphic to the sphere. Learning to work with formulas like this is just a matter of getting practice with using formulas to describe geometric relationships. When you read other people's formulas, sit down and try to figure out for yourself why the formula does what it's supposed to do; eventually you'll start getting ideas about how to write your own.

Comment: @JackLee. Yes. Initially i want to use the Classification theorem of surface but i'm just getting nowhere. Thank you prof for the advice. I'll try that.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to map $S^2$ diffeomorphically to $W^2=\{x^4+y^2+z^2=1\}\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is by

$$(x,y,z)\mapsto(x,\sqrt{1+x^2}\cdot y,\sqrt{1+x^2}\cdot z).$$

This map is obviously smooth with a smooth inverse, and it is well defined as shown immediately.

Comment: Although this is not a universal method for such kind of question, your construction is really wonder cause the map is a diffeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3$, may I know how you constructed such a clever mapping?