# $x^{4}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1$ diffeomorphic to 2-sphere $\mathbb{S}^{2}$

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is homework so no answers please

The problem is: $A=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^{3}: x^{4}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1\}$ is diffeomorphic to 2-sphere $\mathbb{S}^{2}$.

Any mistakes:

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^{3}\setminus \{0\}\to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ defined as $f(x,y,z)=(\sqrt{x},y,z)$. This is a smooth map so its restriction to $f':A\to \mathbb{S}^{2}$ is also smooth with smooth inverse $f(x,y,z)=(x^{2},y,z)$. Bijectivity follows easily.

Yeah so the problem is A will not be contained in $\mathbb{R}^{3}\setminus \{0\}$.  I want to avoid going through the coordinate representations. Let alone that I will have to show A is a submanifold.

Any hints?

Thanks

Comment: $\sqrt x$ is not smooth near $x=0$.

Comment: That's why I took out the zero. But on second look A will not be contained in $\mathbb{R}^{3}-\{0\}$.

Comment: Anywhere near $x=0$, not necessarily $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: I think the radial projection $\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb S^2$ is smooth.

Comment: my only problem with working with $x^{4}+s^{2}+t^{2}=1$ is that I will have to show it is a manifold. I suppose I could do it, since it is the graphs of functions.

Comment: Or can I treat $x^{4}+s^{2}+t^{2}=1$ as a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ to get a smooth map on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is $\{(x,y,z,0)\in\mathbb{R}^4:x^4+y^2+z^2=1\}$ diffeomorphic to $S^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/893410/is-x-y-z-0-in-mathbbr4x4y2z2-1-diffeomorphic-to-s2)